# Lock a cell in a column when a user types "-" character

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, and I would like to write such a code that when a user types "-" sign in the cells in the Column number 11 (K2:K100), the only current cell can be locked automatically, not all cells below the current one. The other cells within that column can be locked after the "-" sign is entered again. I written down the code below so that you can help me. I searched a lot on internet but could not find the exact solution to my problem.

The problem is that when I lock the second cell, it requires me to type "Yes" twice. The third cell requires three times, and so on. It also applies to the cases with "No".

Also, all cells in the column get locked.

I appreciate any help in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Value = "-" Then    
        Dim Source As String    
        Source = "Do you want to unlock the password"

        changeInput = MsgBox(Source, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Unlock the sheet")    
        If changeInput = vbYes Then    
            Dim pass As String    
            pass = InputBox("Enter the password")

            If pass <> "test" Then    
                MsgBox ("Wrong Password")    
            Else    
                ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="test"    
                Target.Locked = False    
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range    
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="test"    
    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K100")    
    If cel = "-" Then    
        check = MsgBox("The cell will be locked after minus sign.", vbYesNo, "Warning")    
        If check = vbYes Then
            cel.Locked = True 
        Else    
            cel.Value = ""    
        End If    
        End If
        Next cel
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="test"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code? What is your question? You didn't ask one yet.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add my question. You can see it now.

Comment: In which line do you get the error? • Note that by default if you start a new worksheet **all** cells are `Locked = True`.

Comment: In this statement I get error : If cel = "-" Then

Comment: You get that type mismach because `cel` is a range `K2:K100` and not a single cell. So `cel` is not a single value but an array of values. If you want to check all of them for `"-"` you need to loop through them and check every single cell in `K2:K100

Comment: Then how should I define cel as a single cell ? I changed the statement to For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K100").

Comment: Now, the problem is that when I lock the second cell, it requires me to type "Yes" twice. The third cell requires three times, and so on. It also applies to "No".

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Please give a better example of the issue.

Comment: For example, in the first cell (K2) of (K2:K100), when I enter any sign, the window pops up. After I click the YES button, it locks all cells in this range. Interestingly, when I enter any sign in the second cell, the window pops up again and requires Yes twice and again all cells are locked. I mean each cell requires YES and NO window according to its number. Also, unfortunately, the cells are locked when any value is entered, not exactly "-" sign. I need cells are locked in that column only if minus sign is entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by default **all cells** in the entire sheet are locked unless you unlock them. So to make the following work make sure you unlock all cells in range `"K2:K100"`.

The following will lock any cell in `"K2:K100"` if you enter a minus `-`. And it will unlock the cell if you double click and enter the correct password.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SHEET_PASSWORD As String = "test"  '‹~~ only write your password once or you will have to change it in multiple places later

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Value = "-" Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to unlock the cell?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Unlock cell") = vbYes Then
            On Error GoTo CANCEL_UNLOCK
            Me.Unprotect
            On Error GoTo 0

            On Error GoTo REPROTECT_SHEET
            If Not Me.ProtectContents Then
                Target.Locked = False
            Else
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

REPROTECT_SHEET:
            're-protect the sheet, so only the target cell gets unlocked
            Me.Protect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'report error if there is one
                Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
                Cancel = True
            End If
        Else
            'if user presses 'no' then cancel double-click to prevent additional message
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If


    Exit Sub
CANCEL_UNLOCK:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Wrong Password", vbCritical, "Unlock cell"
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Cancel = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SheetWasInitiallyProtected As Boolean
    SheetWasInitiallyProtected = Me.ProtectContents

    Me.Unprotect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD
    On Error GoTo REPROTECT_SHEET 'make sure you sheet will always be re-protected in case of error

    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K2:K100"))

    Dim SomethingWasLocked As Boolean  'false by default

    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then 'only run the following code if a cell in K2:K100 was changed
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells.Cells
            If Cell.Value = "-" Then
                If MsgBox("Do you want to lock this cell now?", vbYesNo, "Lock cell") = vbYes Then
                    Cell.Locked = True
                    SomethingWasLocked = True
                Else
                    Cell.Value = vbNullString
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If

REPROTECT_SHEET:
    If SomethingWasLocked Or SheetWasInitiallyProtected Then
        Me.Protect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'report error if there is one
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code works perfect. Interestingly, there is one small error that occurs when a user tries to unlock the cell by clicking first Yes and then Cancel. Run-time error '1004': unable to set the locked property of the range class

Comment: When I debug, it highlights this line of the code. Target.Locked = False

Comment: @Alexander well, true. I fixed it and added a check if the sheet got unprotected. If not it cancels the unlock of the cell.

Comment: I just observed one problem regarding the code. When I add any input in the other cells or delete and add the columns, the sheet automatically gets locked. Any idea?

Comment: @Alexander yes, I adjusted the code of the `Worksheet_Change` accordingly. Now it only protects the sheet if it was protected before or if somthing was locked by adding a `-`.